# How to make Left Vertical Menu > Sub Items visible to screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am creating a website in WordPress and it has lots of Menu Items > Sub Menu items

Website Link: https://new.chefiality.pk

The issue is if I select hover the last Main Menu items then the div contains Sub Menu item cut down the screen

Video: https://www.loom.com/share/0bfb9eed120241fdb41ba250479ab720

I use this code

```
.header-vertical .main-nav .menu .menu-item-design-default>.sub-menu-dropdown, .header-vertical .main-nav .menu .menu-item-design-full-width>.sub-menu-dropdown, .header-vertical .main-nav .menu .menu-item-design-sized>.sub-menu-dropdown {
overflow: unset;
}
```

But it's not working. Can someone guide me on what to do.

Regards.

Comment: You have many menu items, in addition to not displaying submenus, the last menu items are not displayed while scrolling.

Comment: You need to add this style to get your menu `fixed`. You have to modify the other styles as well. `.header-vertical{position:absolute!important}`

Comment: its still same, nothing happen

Comment: Do you have a cache plugin? If you have, clear the cache.